# Is there a line of code which I can run to get unique values from one column based on a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, jupyter

I have done a groupby on a df in order to group the columns based on its country code. I.e.:

```
DataGroup = df.groupby('COUNTRY_CODE').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Name'))
DataGroup
```

and I have managed to group all the columns based on the Country Code that the belong to. Now I would like to get the unique Names from the Name Column from each Country Code grouping so that For example in 'UK', if the column contains the names: ['John', 'Mary', 'Fatema', 'John'], how would I only be presented with the unique values in the column of the df?

Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can achieve this by using drop_duplicates and specifying the subset you check for: `DataGroup.drop_duplicates(subset=["COUNTRY_CODE", "Name"])`

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([("NO", "John"),
                   ("NO", "Jane"),
                   ("NO", "John"),
                   ("SE", "Ville")], columns=["COUNTRY_CODE","Name"])
DataGroup = df.groupby('COUNTRY_CODE').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Name'))
print(DataGroup)
DataGroup = DataGroup.drop_duplicates(subset=["COUNTRY_CODE", "Name"])
print(DataGroup)

Output:
               COUNTRY_CODE   Name
COUNTRY_CODE                      
NO           1           NO   Jane
             0           NO   John
             2           NO   John
SE           3           SE  Ville
               COUNTRY_CODE   Name
COUNTRY_CODE                      
NO           1           NO   Jane
             0           NO   John
SE           3           SE  Ville
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help :)